# WinFF problem with AVI

Tags: winff

I have an old DVD player that works best with AVI format. Now I have strange problem with WinFF. It works most of the time fine. But quite often conversions work fine on my computer, but in my DVD player it stops long before the movie is ended. The original format doesn't matter.

It's not much to go by, but what might be the reason?

Comment: Which preset are you using to produce your avi files?

Comment: The original torrents I download. I look at the properties, and set the audio and video the same. Say, the movie is MP4, I look for those settings and use them when converting to AVI.

Comment: Hmmm.... I have a similar issue but I use bare FFmpeg to make the conversion to avi, usually with mpeg4 (Xvid) video and mp3 audio. I could make up a WinFF  preset for you to try or simply give the FFmpeg syntax? Also which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm running 16.04

Comment: And you are running your files from a USB drive into your player or actually burning avi files onto a DVD disk for playback?

Comment: The latter.  I download a torrent, convert it. Then I put it on a usb stick to watch it on the DVD player. Only when it works (which is most of the time) I sometimes burn it on a DVD.

Comment: Pretty much my own usage, try the WinFF preset that I have given in my answer. I can modify it if necessary, tested on 16.04...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with an older device and to allow playback I devised a successful encode with FFmpeg that can easily enough be wrapped up in a WinFF preset.

First make sure that you have a *full* WinFF installation:

```
sudo apt-get install winff winff-doc ffmpeg libavcodec-extra
```

Then create a file on your desktop called called `torrent2tv.wff` and copy and paste the following xml snippet into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<presets> 
  <TORRENT2TV>
    <label>Convert to avi for viewing through old device!</label>
    <params>-c:v mpeg4 -q:v 2 -vtag XVID -sn -mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -q:a 3 -ar 44100 </params>
    <extension>avi</extension>
    <category>My Presets</category>
  </TORRENT2TV>
</presets>
```

Right click on this file and select 'Open With WinFF' and this will be enough to install your preset into a new category called 'My Presets'.

Select this and run you input torrent files and hopefully your playback will be as good as mine on my own aged device :).